@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.8.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times
I keep getting this error message while I try to run my ionic app on my android devices.
Most of the question avaiable with same message has permission denied but in my case its [code=unavailable]
 @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.8.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I really have fast internet connection and not sure why this appear. There were issue with ios as well but I have manage to fixed with some condition. But for android its not working with any of the condition.
I am using Ionic Angular 17 with firebase.
my app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { QuillModule, provideQuillConfig } from 'ngx-quill';

import { provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getFirestore, initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import {provideFirebaseApp} from "@angular/fire/app";
import { Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";
import { getAuth, initializeAuth, indexedDBLocalPersistence } from "firebase/auth"
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);

const firestoreDB = initializeFirestore(getApp(), {
  experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true
})
// TODO comment for ios app
// const auth = getAuth(app);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,

    // provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    // provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        return firestoreDB
      } else {
        return getFirestore();
      }
    }),
    provideAuth(() => {
      if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
          persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
        })
      } else {
        return  getAuth(app);
      }
    }),

    // TODO comment for ios app
    // provideAuth(() => auth),

    QuillModule.forRoot({
      modules: {
        syntax: false,
        toolbar: {
          container: [
            [{ align: [] }],
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
            ["link"],
            [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
            [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
          ],
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}


